# Why $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] sometimes return uppercase?

Tags: php

I use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to check my script running on correct domain and send an email when it runs on illegal domain. The problem is that sometimes I receive incorrect alerts that script run on incorrect domain. It is a false alert with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in uppercase.

First, why this happen?
Second, is this safe to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or is there a better why?

Note: I didn't convert value to lowercase in my code.

Comment: if you're including it from another file, then it can be faked...

Comment: @home it would be if it's using $_SERVER.

Comment: @pgl: Apologies, that's why I asked - I do not know PHP :-) Added PHP tag.

Comment: @home Oh, no worries - I didn't mean to sound rude, sorry!

Comment: @home yes that is PHP ;) thanks for tag

Comment: @CharmingPrince : I get same alert from my secured server. I am sure I am not hacked :D and there is not included file

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is the hostname that the script was accessed by. So, if someone goes to http://WWW.EXAMPLE.COM/ it'll be uppercase.

It's safe to check, just convert it to lowercase with strtolower() first.

Edit: I say it's safe to check, but there is one caveat: user agents using HTTP/1.0 won't supply a Host: header, so $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] will be unset. This is very unlikely to happen, but if you want to protect against it make sure you code for that possibility.

Comment: but all web browsers convert domains to lowercase automatically and I do not get alert when type it in uppercase.

Comment: Then it would be a good idea for you to post the code that generates the alert, along with some sample output.

Comment: here is it: <code>
 
 $valid_domain="example.com";
 

 if(@strpos(@$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],$valid_domain)===FALSE)
  @mail('toemail', 'alert', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); 
 

 // I get EXAMPLE.COM sometimes in emailed alert.
</code>

Comment: I can't reproduce an upper case HOST with a standard browser but there may be some bookmark plugin etc that manages to create them. While most of the upper case HTTP_HOST instances seem to be definitely badly written robots I did find at least one valid looking user sending an upper case host with an agent of "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36".